# Python: How do I change items between lists?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to code the 2048 game, and I'm stuck at the move up/down part.
So ex, if I've a list like this:

```
2 0 2 4 
0 8 2 4
4 4 2 0
0 4 0 2
```

I want to move my numbers up, so I've something like this:

```
2 8 2 4
4 4 2 4
0 4 2 2
0 0 0 0
```

And I don't know how to even begin, someone can give me tips?
I tried this but it only works for a identity matrix:

```
new_matrix = [] 
for line in matrix: 
    for pos, element in enumerate(line): 
        if element != 0: 
            new_matrix.append(element) 
            line[pos] = 0 
list.clear(matrix[0]) 
matrix[0] = new_matrix 
return (matrix)
```

Comment: How did you go from the first example? How do you expect help without describing what you want to achieve?

Comment: It's bc it's a little difficult to explain, but i'll try. Let me edit it.

Comment: Putting your task into words and making it clear is a key step in being able to solve it. Will be happy to give this a shot when you describe it.

Comment: I update it, Idk if now it's clear

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the list, check which index contains 0, let's say (`n`) then assign the value of the next elements `n`th index, and make next elements `n`th index `0`:

```
A = [[1,0,2,1],[0,1,3,4],[4,5,1,0],[0,3,0,1]]

length = len(A)

for i, elem in enumerate(A):
    for j, item in enumerate(elem):
        if item == 0 and i + 1 < length:
            A[i][j] = A[i+1][j]
            A[i+1][j] = 0

print(A)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 1], [4, 5, 3, 4], [0, 3, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

For the current example:

```
>>> A
[[2, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 8, 2, 4],
 [4, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 2]]

>>> for i, elem in enumerate(A):
        for j, item in enumerate(elem):
            if item == 0 and i + 1 < length:
                A[i][j] = A[i+1][j]
                A[i+1][j] = 0

>>> A

[[2, 8, 2, 4],
 [4, 4, 2, 4],
 [0, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```